# How remove ORDER BY in SQL query in Oracle Forms

Tags: sql, oracleforms

I have a SQL query that is generated under certain conditions, when the F7/F8. The generated SQL query is inserted into the block "Block1" through LAST_QUERY.

LAST_QUERY my returns SQL query:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, sloupec4, sloupec5, sloupec6
FROM table
WHERE column1 = 12
AND column2 = 'test'
ORDER BY column1, column3 desc, column 5;
```

If the SQL query from LAST_QUERY I put the block through

```
v_where =: System.Last_Query;
set_block_property('BLOCK1' default_where, v_where);
```

After you do this, show error and SQL query looks as follows:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, sloupec4, sloupec5, sloupec6
FROM table
WHERE column1 = 12
AND column2 = 'test'
ORDER BY column1, column3 desc, column 5 ORDER BY column1, column3 desc, column 5;
```

How do I remove everything behind ORDER BY including ORDER BY?
There are some SQL functions to remove the last several characters in a SQL query?

ORDER BY I have on block "BLOCK1" and I can not remove it, it must stay there.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Does the block is based on a database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove order by clause from your v_where variable:

```
v_where := :SYSTEM.LAST_QUERY;
if instr(v_where, 'ORDER BY') > 0 then
  v_where := substr(v_where, 1, instr(v_where, 'ORDER BY')-1);
end if;
```

Comment: Thank you, this it exactly what I needed.
I have to repeat the basics of Oracle SQL :-)